# index out of bound from TabViewStyle of SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

I am trying to implement a tabView that takes a list of items into pages that I could swipe back and forth. However, it keeps bugging out with an "index out of bound" error. It's confusing to me because I never set index at all, and I don't know how to force an index either...

Below are my code. Apologize for any naive code, I am new to SwiftUI. Any helps are appreciated, thank you!

```
import SwiftUI

//@Published private var list = QuestionList.self
struct QuestionList: Codable {
    var list:[QuestionItem]
}

class QuestionItem: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var text: String
    var type: Int
    var answer: String
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var qlist = [QuestionItem]()
    @State private var isShowForm = false
    @State private var q1 = true
    @State private var answer = ""
    @State private var isOn = [Bool]()
    @State private var selectedTab = 0
    func showForm() {
        isShowForm = !isShowForm
        let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/question")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                  (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
                      print(response)
                      return
                  }
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }
            do {
                let list = try JSONDecoder().decode([QuestionItem].self, from:data)
                qlist = list
                print(qlist[1])
                for i in 0..<qlist.count {
                    isOn.append(qlist[i].type == 0)
                }
                print(isOn)
//                print(isOn)
                print(type(of: qlist[1]))
            } catch {
                print("error: ", error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
        Button("Open Form") {
            self.showForm()
        }

        if (isShowForm) {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                ForEach(qlist.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    if qlist[index].type == 0 {
                        HStack {
                            Text("\(self.qlist[index].text)")
//                            Toggle("", isOn: $isOn[index])
                            Toggle("", isOn: $q1)
                        }
                    } else {
                        VStack {
                            Text("\(self.qlist[index].text)")
//                                .lineLimit(2)
//                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
//                                .frame(width: 300)
                            TextField("Enter your answer here:", text: $qlist[index].answer) {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
        .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not recommended to use `indices` in `ForEach` loops,  instead use something like this:
`ForEach(qlist) { qItem in
            if qItem.type == 0 { ... }
            ...
        }` and of course remove the `print(qlist[1])` and `print(type(of: qlist[1]))` in `showForm`.

Comment: @workingdog it makes sense, but it pops up an error around `TextField("Enter your answer here:", text: $qlist.answer)`, which says value of the type 'Binding<[QuestionItem]>' has no dynamic member 'answer' using key path from root type '[QuestionItem]'

Comment: see my answer with updated code.

Comment: You will ALWAYS expose yourself to trouble if you mix code like this.
1 - Move the request code somewhere in a 'Network' class/struct
2 - in the .onAppear handler of the view or class, execute your request by calling something like `Network.fetchItems`
3 - on completion of your request, set the @state items array, and the view will refresh. Now you can test/modify your request on one side, and work on the UI on the other side. Just a solid advice. Keep it up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to use indices in `ForEach` loops,  instead use something like this updated code
that allows you to use your `TextField` :

```
            ForEach($qlist) { $qItem in  // <-- here $
                 if qItem.type == 0 {
                     HStack {
                         Text(qItem.text)
//                            Toggle("", isOn: $isOn[index])
                         Toggle("", isOn: $q1)
                     }
                 } else {
                     VStack {
                         Text(qItem.text)
//                                .lineLimit(2)
//                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                             .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
//                                .frame(width: 300)
                         TextField("Enter your answer here:", text: $qItem.answer) {
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
```

and as I mentioned in my comment, remove the `print(qlist[1])` and `print(type(of: qlist[1]))` in `showForm`,
because if  `qlist` is empty or only has one element, you will get the index out of bound error .
Remember one element is  `qlist[0]`.

EDIT-1: full test code:

this is the code I used in my test. It does not give any index errors.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
 
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var qlist = [QuestionItem]()
    
    @State private var isShowForm = false
    @State private var q1 = true
    @State private var answer = ""
    @State private var isOn = [Bool]()
    @State private var selectedTab = 0
    
    func showForm() {
        let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/question")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                  (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
                    //  print(response)
                      return
                  }
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }
            do {
                let list = try JSONDecoder().decode([QuestionItem].self, from:data)
                qlist = list
  //              print(qlist[1])
                for i in 0..<qlist.count {
                    isOn.append(qlist[i].type == 0)
                }
                print(isOn)
//                print(isOn)
    //            print(type(of: qlist[1]))
                isShowForm.toggle()   // <--- here important
            } catch {
                print("error: ", error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
        Button("Open Form") {
          //  self.showForm()
            // simulate showForm()
            qlist = [
                QuestionItem(id: 0, text: "text0", type: 0, answer: "0"),
                QuestionItem(id: 1, text: "text1", type: 1, answer: "1"),
                QuestionItem(id: 2, text: "text2", type: 2, answer: "2"),
                QuestionItem(id: 3, text: "text3", type: 3, answer: "3")
            ]
           isShowForm.toggle()   // <--- here after qlist is set
        }
        
        if (isShowForm) {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                ForEach($qlist) { $qItem in
                    if qItem.type == 0 {
                        HStack {
                            Text(qItem.text)
                            //  Toggle("", isOn: $isOn[index])
                            Toggle("", isOn: $q1)
                        }
                    } else {
                        VStack {
                            Text(qItem.text)
                            //                                .lineLimit(2)
                            //                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                            //                                .frame(width: 300)
                            TextField("Enter your answer here:", text: $qItem.answer)
                                .border(.red)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
            .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
        }
    }
}

struct QuestionItem: Codable, Identifiable {  // <-- here note the struct
    var id: Int
    var text: String
    var type: Int
    var answer: String
}
```

Comment: thank you for your update and explanation, however, i think the issue remains. i'm pretty much sure its `.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))` where the problem happened... maybe swiftui doesnt recognize which index to read? i searched elsewhere on stackoverflow and saw someone included uuid in the class so i added as well, although I never actually put any value inside, keeping or removing that line both keeps the issue tho.....any other idea?

Comment: updated my answer with my test code. Let us know if this does not work for you.

Comment: no... the problem remains, the current code I came up with was referred with other sample code online, where they use the similar way you did to initialize qlist, or data generally speaking. `qlist = [QuestionItem(id: 0, text: "text0", type: 0, answer: "0")...]` where I used the json data from localhost, which is of form `"id": 1,"text": "qwertyu",  "type": 0,"answer": "0"` ... etc, could this cause the bug? plus it seems that you didn't modify the foreach loop a lot, so I believe the issue comes from elsewhere

Comment: you mean that your question is about not being able to parse your json data? In that case show what your data is.

Comment: to show what data you are getting from the server, add
 `print("----> response: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))")` just after 
`guard let data = data else {  return  }` in your `showForm`. Can you tell us on what line of my code you get the index error.

Comment: the output is something like: `----> response: Optional("[\n  {\n    \"id\": 1,\n    \"text\": \"Is person able to get up the stairs?\",\n    \"type\": 0,\n    \"answer\": \"0\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"id\": 2,\n    \"text\": \"Are there multiple entrances to get into house?\",\n    \"type\": 0,\n    \"answer\": \"0\"\n  },\n`. Plus I think the only line causing index out of bound bug was `.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))`, when I commented this line, the program goes smoothly.

Comment: double checked your code, it worked perfectly, the only difference from mine is that you define qlist manually, is that the place where I got wrong?

Comment: there are no problems decoding your data, however I just saw that in `showForm() `you have
`isShowForm = !isShowForm`
at the very beginning. This is wrong, move this to just before `catch {}` inside the task closure.
That should fix the error. PS, you can also use the more common form `isShowForm.toggle()`. I'll update my answer with this.

Comment: oh my god, it works now, thank you so much!!!!!!!! could you please explain it little bit? How did my initial code `isShowForm = !isShowForm` wrong, both position-wise and logic-wise?

Comment: well it's very simple, you have to "wait" until your `qlist` is ready with the data. Only after that can you toggle the  `isShowForm`, not before as you were doing. Since `URLSession.shared.dataTask` is an asynchronous function, you have to do this inside its closure.

Comment: oh i dont know URLSession is an asynchronous function, does SwiftUI has something similar to JavaScript where I can force a synchronous processing using await?

Comment: yes, swift has a number of ways to do this. One recent addition to the language is the async/await concurrency pattern. There is also the popular more traditional completion closure. Personally  I think the async/await is great.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you for asnwering all my questions!